# Determine if an acid base reaction will occur

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

I'm wondering why some acid base reactions occur, let's say for example:

$$\ce{CH3CH2OH + H2O <<=> CH3CH2O- + H3O+}$$

Why does this reaction occur, because the alkoxide ion is a really strong base right?

Why should its conjugate acid give off a $\ce{H+}$ to water, if it was a strong base let's say $\ce{NaOH}$ it would make sense to me, because the $\ce{OH-}$ is probably a stronger base then the alkoxide ion.

**Question:**
Why does the above reaction take place, considering the fact that water is a really weak base?

Comment: Certainly *some* of the amine will be protonated. The extent to which that happens depends on the equilibrium constant.

Comment: so an acid base reaction will Always occur? @MaxW

Comment: $$\ce{CH3CH2NHCH3 + H2O <=> NH2(CH3)(CH2CH3)^+ + OH^- }$$

Comment: If you're asking generally then it's much to broad.

Comment: I narrowed my question down, hopfully you can help me now @Mithoron

Comment: You seem to have understood it, given that you have shown in the size of your arrows that the equilibrium lies mostly to the left hand side. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: I would think the reaction won't happen at all, because the alkoxide ion is a really strong base so why would it's conjugated acid (CH3CH2OH) donate it's H+ to H2O at all? @bon

Comment: @RickBeeloo Every reaction is an equilibrium. Its just that for some reactions, the equilibrium lies far to the products or reactants side. Here, the equilibrium will lie far to the reactants side.

Comment: @RickBeeloo **Don't** edit your questions to make them into different questions. Ask new questions instead.

Comment: Yeah I want to but stackexchange says I can't because these 2 haven't been answered yet @bon

Comment: @RickBeeloo I'll give you an answer to this one later when I'm free.

Comment: OH- is not a stronger base than the alkoxide ion.

Comment: Ow ok, but if the alkoxide ion is so strong, why should it's conjugated acid undergo a reaction'? Because it don't want to lose it's proton? @orthocresol

Comment: It does but only to a very small extent, as bon already indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to realise is that **every reaction is in equilibrium**, but some reactions have an equilibrium so far to one side that they are effectively complete (or they don't go at all). The position of equilibrium is determined by the relative stability of the products and the reactants. $$\ce{CH3CH2OH + H2O <<=> CH3CH2O- + H3O+}$$

The strength of acids can be compared by looking at $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values. The $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of $\ce{H3O+}$ in water is -1.7 and the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of ethanol in water is 16. So you are correct that hydronium is a much stronger acid than ethanol - or equivalently, ethoxide is a much stronger base than water. However, *some* of the water will deprotonate the ethanol and so the reaction will go to a small extent. This is why the equilibrium arrows are written with a big arrow on the reverse reaction and a small arrow on the forward reaction.

The equilibrium constant for the reaction is related to the standard Gibbs energy change for the reaction by: $$\Delta_\mathrm{r} G^\circ = -RT\ln K$$